# Django registration with i18n

Tags: django, internationalization, translation

My question is about the best way to translate the email activation template of django-registration.

If i have 2 languages should i do 2 email templates, one for each language or should i use blocktrans to translate the whole thing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use blocktrans for translate your templates. For example look here:

https://github.com/dokterbob/django-registration-templates

This include translations for nl and de languages.